# How to get product collection of given main category id?

Tags: magento, collections, categories, program-entry-point, product

In my website I have several stores available. One particular store contains both the simple and configurable products. This is a huge collection of products. What is the fastest way to get all enabled products (including child products of configurable products) collection of this store by store id?

Note: I tried this lot of different ways. But it takes loo much time. Sometimes cause to crash the server even.

Note : I'm using `Magento CE 1.3`

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: what data are you looking for? in what format?

Comment: I want to get the product collection of that store including their attributes as well.

Comment: Follow this links, you may get help
[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503534/display-magento-products-by-category-id

Answer (score 0):

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name', 'url_key','price','lowest_price','service_id','description','short_description'));

$collection->addStoreFilter();
```

instead of use addAttributeToSelect('*') use only specific attributes which you needed because it effect performance of site

hope this will help you