# Display magento products by category ID

Tags: magento, e-commerce, php, mage

I need to know how can I display products in a page like (cart, below total) only few products by ID. Eg: products with id 2,3,4 and 5.

```
<div class="freeProducts voucher code">
    <?php

    $categoryid = 64;

    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load($categoryid);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>

    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

At this moment I can see the image for each product, and the title. I need to display the ADD TO CART and price.

Anyone can help please?

Comment: What did you try so far? Could you show us some code?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @admdrew I need to display all the products from a particular category. At the first try i started to find how to display products by ID but i realised that its good to add the products within a category and then display all the products from that category. I added my code  and i need some informations

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**get Product from specific category**

```
$categoryIds = array(2,4);//category id

$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                             ->getCollection()
                             ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                             ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
```

**get Product for specific product id**

```
$productids = array(52,62);//product ids
$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');
$collection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array( 'in' => $productids));
```

**then write this in phtml**

```
<?php $_collectionSize = $collection->count() ?>
    <?php //$_columnCount = $this->getColumnCount(); ?>
    <?php $i=0; foreach ($collection as $product): ?>
        <?php if ($i++%4==0): ?>
        <ul class="products-grid">
        <?php endif ?>
            <li class="item<?php if(($i-1)%$_columnCount==0): ?> first<?php elseif($i%$_columnCount==0): ?> last<?php endif; ?>">
                <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $product->getName()?>">
                        <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image')->resize(197, 167); ?>" alt="<?php echo $product->getName()?>" border="0" />
                    </a>
                <h2 class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl()?>" title="<?php echo $product->getName()?>"><?php echo $product->getName() ?></a></h2>
               <div class="price-box">
               <?php echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($product->getPrice(),true,false);?>
               </div>
                <div class="actions">
                    <?php if($product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/')?>product/<?php echo $product->getId() ?>/')" title="<?php echo $this->__('Köp');?>" type="submit"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Köp');?></span></span></button>
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>

                </div>
            </li>
        <?php if ($i%$_columnCount==0 || $i==$_collectionSize): ?>
        </ul>
        <?php endif ?>
        <?php endforeach ?>
```

hope this help you

Comment: Hi there! The code you provide helped me a lot, but I have an issue. Just 12 products are listed(for 2 categories array), and if in the array is just 1 category id, it doesn't list anything. Do you have any ideeas?

Answer (score 10):

```
// print_r($productslist)
 $category_id = 14; // if you know static category then enter number

$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 

$collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection');

$collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product

$collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','small_image')); //add product attribute to be fetched

//$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()'); //uncomment to get products in random order     

$collection->addStoreFilter();          

if(!empty($collection))

{

        foreach ($collection as $_product):?>

        <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl();?>"><img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(197, 167); ?>" />   </a>  

 <?php   endforeach;

}else

    {

        echo 'No products exists';

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$categoryid = 123;
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($categoryid);
$productCollection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
->addCategoryFilter($_category);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    <?php 
 require "../app/Mage.php";
 Mage::app();
    ?>


  <table>
  <?php 
 $ris_arr = array(39,77,78,79);
 foreach ($ris_arr as &$value) { 
  ?>
 <tr><td style="background-color:#foo;margin-top:50px;">
 <?php 
$ris_value = $value;
 $category_id = $ris_value; // if you know static category then enter number

$catagory_model = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($category_id); 

  $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')->setPageSize(4);;

   $collection->addCategoryFilter($catagory_model); //category filter

   $collection->addAttributeToFilter('status',1); //only enabled product

   $collection->addAttributeToSelect(array('name','url','small_image','price','sku')); //add product attribute to be fetched

     //$collection->getSelect()->order('rand()'); //uncomment to get products in random order     

    $collection->addStoreFilter();          

    if(!empty($collection))

    { ?>
   <div style="width:100%">
     <?php  foreach ($collection as $_product):?>
      <div style="width:200px;float:left">
     <?php $pro_url= $_product->getProductUrl(); 
  $pro_url2=str_replace("rishabh_daily_report_cron2.php/","",$pro_url);?>
   <a href="<?php echo $pro_url2;?>">
      <img src="<?php echo Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(197, 167); ?>" />   </a> 
         <?php 
      echo $_product->getName()."<br>";
  //echo $_product->getSku()."<br>";
  echo $_product->getSpecialPrice();
    ?>
        </div>

    <?php   endforeach; ?>
    </div>
     <?php
         }else

      {

    echo 'No products exists';

       }
       echo "</td></tr>";  
       } 
      ?>      
       <table>
```