# Get price and Add to cart button Magento

Tags: php, html, css, magento

I create a block where I display all the products from a category by its ID. 
At this moment I can see the title of the product and its image, but i need the (ADD TO CART) and the (PRICE). My code is:

```
<div class="freeProducts voucher code">
    <?php

    $categoryid = 64;

    $category = new Mage_Catalog_Model_Category();
    $category->load($categoryid);
    $collection = $category->getProductCollection();
    $collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($collection as $_product) { ?>

    <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(200); ?>" width="200" height="200" alt="" /></a> <a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl(); ?>"><?php echo $_product->getName(); ?></a>
    <button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>

    <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: pls create a http://jsfiddle.net/ file

Comment: @ DOCTYPE HTML: I'm not aware jsfiddle supports magento code ? @ CRISS: please explain what goes wrong, because I don't really understand the problem.

Comment: check this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19503534/display-magento-products-by-category-id/19510529#19510529

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated button code:

Remove:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getAddToCartUrl($_item) ?>')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

Add:

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="setLocation('<?php echo Mage::getUrl('checkout/cart/add/')?>product/<?php echo $_product->getId() ?>/')"><span><span><?php echo $this->__('Add to Cart') ?></span></span></button>
```

`$this->getAddToCartUrl($_item)` will not work in custom code. This is used in product detail page  where helper is called.

Comment: How can i solve the add to cart button error, https://justpaste.it/6fi1f   Your code also not working.