# Magento Foreach subcategory get products list

Tags: html, css, magento, php

I will explain my situation first of all.

Currently I created a block where I display all categories from One main category. I get its subcategories using the id of the main category.
**Result:**
[image: This is the list of my categories]

**"All products"** is a link to the current category.
Below "All products" li item i need to display all products of current category.
**My current progress:**

```
<div class="block block-category">
    <div class="inside-box">
    <div class="block-title block-category-title"><h2><?php echo $this->__('Product List') ?></h2></div>
        <div class="block-category-navigation">
            <ul id="category-nav"> 
            <?php 
            $root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5); 
            $subCat = explode(',',$root->getChildren()); 

            $collection  = $root
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect("*")
                         ->addFieldToFilter("entity_id", array("in", $subCat) );

                    foreach($collection as $catname){ ?>
                        <li class="clickToSeeProducts">
                            <a>
                                <?php echo $catname->getName(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>  
                        <div class="toggleDiv"><a class="allProducts" href="<?php echo $catname->getURL(); ?>"><?php echo "All Products"; ?></li></a></div>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```

**Any idea how to display my products using my method?
Thank you**

Comment: The categories which you have shown above are both main and sub categories right?

Comment: Are all subcategories of the category with ID-5 
$root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5)

Answer (score 0):

Try this: (*not tested*)  [source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19510529/1577396)

```
<div class="block block-category">
    <div class="inside-box">
    <div class="block-title block-category-title"><h2><?php echo $this->__('Product List') ?></h2></div>
        <div class="block-category-navigation">
            <ul id="category-nav"> 
            <?php 
                $root = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load(5); 
                foreach ($root->getChildren() as $subCat) {
                    $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                                     ->getCollection()
                                     ->joinField('category_id', 'catalog/category_product', 'category_id', 'product_id = entity_id', null, 'left')
                                     ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
                                     ->addAttributeToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoryIds))
                    foreach($collection as $catname){ ?>
                        <li class="clickToSeeProducts">
                            <a>
                                <?php echo $catname->getName(); ?>
                            </a>
                        </li>  
                        <div class="toggleDiv"><a class="allProducts" href="<?php echo $catname->getURL(); ?>"><?php echo "All Products"; ?></li></a></div>
                    <?php } 
                }
            ?>
            </ul>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</div>
```